# Danger of leaked PSK (password) in IPsec tunnel

Tags: vpn, firewall, ipsec, pfsense

Let us say I have a IPSEC tunnel between a Pfsense firewall and a Cisco firewall. In the Pfsense panel, when configuring a Site-to-site VPN between them, there is a PSK which is common in both ends, and other configuration options - the encryption algorithm is AES-256and hash is SHA1; the authentication method is mutual PSK.

My question is related to the PSK or Pre-Shared key. What happens if it is a weak password? Can people create a second IPSEC tunnel with one of the both ends? Or is it just that people who sniffs traffic between the two endpoints in the connection can decrypt the packets? I ask because I see the message "This key should be long and random to protect the tunnel and its contents. A weak PSK can lead to a tunnel compromise"

Let me know if more information is necessary

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Someone could access the data in flight, or DDoS one of the ends off and attach to the other in its place. You'll never type this key, it is used host to host so the other side will need it too. The fact that you are asking this means you likely will never replace the key either.